# why does string get moved 1 to the right when using BinaryWriter?

Tags: c#

really need some help with this...

i got a string in a file: `SaveStation_001`

which is in hex: `53 61 76 65 53 74 61 74 69 6F 6E 5F 30 30 31`

I wrote this in C#

```
private void s_PlayerSStation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BinaryWriter m_bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName));
    if (textBox3.Text == "")
    {
        m_bw.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number before pressing the button", "Save Station Error");
        return;
    }
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
    if (x > 999)
    {
        m_bw.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Value exceeds max");
        return;
    }
    if (textBox3.Text.Length < 3)
    {
        if (textBox3.Text.Length < 2)
        {
            string p = String.Format("00{0}", textBox3.Text);
            m_bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x00000004;
            m_bw.Write(p);
            m_bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x000038BC;
            m_bw.Write(p);
            label4.Text = String.Format("You will now spawn a save station: {0}", textBox3.Text);
            m_bw.Close();
            return;
        }
        string z = String.Format("0{0}", textBox3.Text);
        m_bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x00000004;
        m_bw.Write(z);
        m_bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x000038BC;
        m_bw.Write(z);
        label4.Text = String.Format("You will now spawn a save station: {0}", textBox3.Text);
        m_bw.Close();
        return;
    }
    m_bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x00000004;
    m_bw.Write(textBox3.Text);
    m_bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x000038BC;
    m_bw.Write(textBox3.Text);
    label4.Text = String.Format("You will now spawn a save station: {0}", textBox3.Text);
    m_bw.Close();
}
```

which should only change the number 001 to whatever the user types into textBox3 so lets say i typed in 66 it should just change `SaveStation_001` to `SaveStation_066` but for some reason it shifts it 1 to the right so it looks like this `SaveStation_ 066` (in hex: `53 61 76 65 53 74 61 74 69 6F 6E 5F |03| 30 36 36`). Anyone know what the issue is? also idk where it gets the `03` from in the new hex (marked it with | )

Comment: To make your code indent correctly highlight the code and press the `{ }` button on the toolbar. we do not accept pastebin links to code here.

Comment: well damn it. I did press it but it doesn't do it and gives me a error and its really late here so I don't have time to manually indent it.

Comment: Please, don't be rude *and* do take time, since you are expecting us to give our time to you. Otherwise we might decide not to do so.

Comment: Dunno how I was being rude Peter and thanks Scott.

Comment: Your statement implies that you think that your time is more valuable than ours -- it isn't. Remember that we're volunteers, and it is your responsibility to post well-presented code.

Comment: Just a tip for the future, instead of calling `m_bw.Close()` everywhere just declare it as `using (BinaryWriter m_bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName))) { ... }` with your code in the ..., you don't need to call close as it will close automatically when you leave the using block.

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408(v=vs.110).aspx) of the write call you are making

> Writes a length-prefixed string to this stream in the current encoding of the BinaryWriter

Calling `BinaryWriter.Write(string)` will encode the string's length at the front of the string before it writes, the extra byte you see is that length byte.

What you need to do is use the `BinaryWriter.Write(char[])` overload which will not prefix a length. You can call [`String.ToCharArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert it to the array format.

```
 m_bw.Write(p.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first convert your string to binary.  The [03] is the length of the string being written.

A conversion function:

```
public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string str, Encoding encoding)
{
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```